# How can I make an update fail in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, bdd

I managed to write a test as such for the following update method:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes!(user_update_params)
    render :nothing => true
  end

  context "update user" do   
    it "should update a user based on valid info" do
      @factory = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      put :update, :id => @factory.id, :user => {
         :name => 'sample_user', :user_name => 'sample_user',
         :email => 'sample@gmail.com', :email_confirmation => 'sample@gmail.com',
         :password => 'SamplePassword', :password_confirmation => 'SamplePassword',
         :bio => 'apple sauce', :picture_url => 'http://google.ca'
      }
      assert_equal "sample_user", assigns(:user).name
    end
    it "should not update a user based on invalid info" do
      @factory = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      put :update, :id => @factory.id, :user => {
         :name => 'sample_user', :user_name => 'sample_user',
         :email => 'sample@gmail.com', :email_confirmation => 'sample@gmail.com',
         :password => 'SamplePassword', :password_confirmation => 'asdasdasd',
         :bio => 'apple sauce', :picture_url => 'http://google.ca'
      }
      assigns(:user).valid?.should == false
    end
  end
```

But I am not really sure how to write the opposite of that. I mean I could do `:password_confirmation => 'asdasd'` but when I try that - it states that my password confirmation doesn't match the password and then the test fails 0 it should pass - **this can be seen in the second test**

Any ideas? The test should pass but the validity of the contents going in should be false.

Comment: If you use `update_attributes!` exception ail be raised on error, so you can write a test that checks if exception was raised. (I don't use RSpec anymore so I don't remember name of the test helper to use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was

```
it "should not update a user based on invalid info" do
  assert_raises(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) do
    @factory = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    put :update, :id => @factory.id, :user => {
       :name => 'sample_user', :user_name => 'sample_user',
       :email => 'sample@gmail.com', :email_confirmation => 'sample@gmail.com',
       :password => 'SamplePassword', :password_confirmation => 'asdasdasd',
       :bio => 'apple sauce', :picture_url => 'http://google.ca'
    }
  end
end
```

This passes because - We cannot submit data to the database when the password's do not match.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try fetching the record and testing its current attributes? Like testing if it still have the default attrs and wasn't properly updated.

Something like

```
it "should not update a user based on invalid info" do
  @factory = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  put :update, :id => @factory.id, :user => {
     :name => 'sample_user', :user_name => 'sample_user',
     :email => 'sample@gmail.com', :email_confirmation => 'sample@gmail.com',
     :password => 'SamplePassword', :password_confirmation => 'asdasdasd',
     :bio => 'apple sauce', :picture_url => 'http://google.ca'
  }
  User.first.name.should == 'the factory default name'
  User.first.name.should_not == 'sample_user'
end
```

Comment: problem with that - it states the passwords do not match and thus never gets down to the User.First jazz

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't test any validations in the controller specs. That's the purpose of the model spec. A great way of testing associations and validations is by using the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem.

So back to your specs; Looking at your `update` method I'd write the spec as:

1. First write examples for the *happy path*, (the user is found and the params are valid)
2. Handle the case when `User` with given `id` is not found in the `DB`,
3. Handle the case when the `user` instance wants to be updated with invalid params.

I usually give pay attention to the method calls with specified attributes and assignment of the instance variables.

Hope it helps.

```
context "update user" do
  let(:user_id) { 63 }
  let(:user)    { FactoryGirl.create :user, id: user_id }

  context 'when success' do
    # simplified valid attributes hash
    let(:valid_attributes) { { :name => user_name } }
    let(:user_name) { 'sample_user' }

    it 'should find the user by id passed in params' do
      User.should_receive(:find).with(user_id).and_return(user)

      put :update, :id => user_id, :user => valid_attributes

      assigns(:user).should eq(user)
    end

    it "should update a user based on valid info" do
      put :update, :id => user_id, :user => valid_attributes

      expect(assigns(:user).name).to eq(user_name)
    end
  end

  context 'when failure' do
    let(:invalid_attributes) { {} }

    context 'when a user is not found' do
      let(:user_id) { nil }

      it 'raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception when no user is found'
        User.should_receive(:find).with(user_id).and_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

        put :update, :id => user_id, :user => invalid_attributes
      end
    end

    context 'when a user is found' do
      it "raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception when updated with invalid attributes" do
        User.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes!).with(invalid_attributes).and_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

        put :update, :id => user_id, :user => invalid_attributes
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: problem with this - active record cannot find said record with an id of nil